# asynchronous behavior of nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and I try to render different pages based on some conditions, however, I sometimes meet the problem "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client", I think this is because of the asynchronous behavior of node.js. How can I fix this problem?

I tried setTimeout but I think that's not the right way to do that.

The following part is the section where I met this issue:

```js
/*  
    signup err code:
    0 stand for no errors, 
    1 stand for confirmPassword and password not match
    2 stand for user already exist
*/
app.post('/signup',(req, res) => {
    //initialize the signupErr to be 0
    signupErr = 0;
    //get the data from the post request
    let username = req.body.username;
    let email = req.body.email;
    let password = req.body.password;
    let confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
    let organization = req.body.organization;
    /*first check the twice entered password, if not match set error number to 1 for the server to render the corresponding error message*/
    if (password!=confirmPassword){
        signupErr = 1;
        res.redirect('/signup');
    }
    //form the query to consult the database to check if user exists
    let queryUsername = "SELECT password FROM User WHERE Username = " + "'" + username + "'";
    let queryEmail = "SELECT email FROM User WHERE Email = " + "'" + email + "'";
    // check if username exists

    connection.query(queryEmail,(err,results) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("Errore login: " + err);
        } else if(results.length!=0) {
            signupErr = 2;
            res.redirect('/signup');
        }
    });
    
    //check if email exists
    connection.query(queryUsername,(err,results) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("Errore login: " + err);
        } else if(results.length!=0) {
            signupErr = 2;
            res.redirect('/signup');
        }
    });

    // form the insertion query if no err found
    let queryInsert = "INSERT INTO `PIA`.`User` (`Username`, `Email`, `Password`,`Organization`) VALUES ('"+username +"', '"+ email +"', '"+password +"', '"+organization + "')";
    // insert the data into the database
    connection.query(queryInsert,(err,results) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("Errore login: " + err);
        } else{
            console.log("Inserted");
            res.render('main');
        }
    });
});
```

The insertion part will still run sometime after the redirect.

I'll be really grateful if you can give me any ideas on how to solve that.

Comment: Because you used three asynchronous requests to lead to different pages, I suggest that you can use promises to solve the problem, wrap the three queries into promise objects, and finally use promise.all, which will wait for the three promise objects to be processed. It starts later, and you are here to deal with the action of navigating the webpage

Comment: _"Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"_ - this error suggests that your code is trying to send a response to the client after the response has already been sent.

Comment: First you check the password and redirect, but you don't return so your function continue  to execute and goes to your first `connection.query` that also redirect after some time and then it goes again to a new `connection.query` that blabla.... You got the point, you should end your function call whenever you arrive at a res.redirect

Comment: Note that `res.redirect()` does not stop processing. It will continue executing all other code after it even if it has already sent a HTTP redirect response to the browser. Either add and `else` to everything after it or `return` after calling `res.redirect()`